# Error While Installing @Craco during instaling tailwind css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am facing error while isntalling Tailwind css in react. https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

But in the third step while installing Craco I am facing various error. I am doing it step by step and done around 4-5 times.

I have used npm install @craco/craco

[image: using npm craco]

I have used npm install @craco/craco --save as seen in stackoverflow

[image: uisng npm craco --save]

Comment: Try installing an older version of craco or try updating react-script t the latest version.

Comment: @HamzaKhan i tried but now it start giving me error in npm start.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this or update your react scripts to support craco

npm install @craco/craco@v7.0.0-alpha.0

Hope this works

Comment: Thanks it really worked after 2 week . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update the scripts in package.json then run

npm install @craco/craco --legacy-peer-deps

and

npm install @craco/craco@5.8 --save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).